# Challenging if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n(1-q)q^k$ is equal to 1

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

If I suppose $U(0<q<1)$ as $$U(q) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n(1-q)q^k$$
Do $$A = \lim_{q\to0}U(q)$$ and $$B = \lim_{q\to1}U(q)$$ exist? if so, what we can say about them? e.g. are they really reach each other at value $1$ in $\infty$?

EDIT: SIMPLIFIED
Suppose we both are at value 0, then you start to go to value 1 with speed $q\to0$ and I also but with speed $q\to1$. Do we both reach each other at 1 in $\infty$ while I always am at front of you? it's hard for me to understand this!

Comment: Hint: You can get an explicit formula for $U(q)$. It is $1-q^{n+1}$ for all $q$.

Comment: Good hint, but OP defined $U(q)$ as the limit.

Comment: $U$ is constant on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @Mercy, please re-read because I improved question with more simplified paragraph which descibes what I try to find out.

Comment: You don't make any sense. How do you define $0^0$ then?

Answer (score 1):

Before taking the limit of the function U(q) with respect to variable "q", firstly you should find the value of the function. Then you can take the limit. So
$$U(q)=\lim\limits_{n→∞}\sum_{k=0}^n(1−q)q^k=(1−q)\lim\limits_{n→∞}\sum_{0}^nq^k=\frac{1-q}{1-q}=1$$
Then your function is a constant function such that $ U(q)=1$. So it is independent of limit with respect to variable $q$.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very subtle and important issue in mathematics.  Both $A$ and $B$ are in fact equal to one.  The issue here is that it matters in which order you take the limits.  For instance,

$$1=\lim_{q\to 0} \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^n (1-q) q^k \neq
 \lim_{n\to\infty} \lim_{q\to 0} \sum_{k=0}^n (1-q) q^k=0.$$

In the double limit to the right of the inequality you first take the limit of $q\to 0$, which makes all summands equal to zero and the sum of zeroes equals zero.  In the double limit on the left you first take the limit as $n\to\infty$ which makes the limit equal to one after which you take the limit with respect to $q$, but a limit of a constant sequence equals the constant.

Comment: I was not interested for changing limits sequence. I just have trouble with how both $q\to0$ and $q\to1$ reach each other at value 1 while they have different speeds.

Comment: Yes, and my response explains precisely why that happens.  It is because you're reversing the order in which limits are taken.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not get again :( Suppose we both are at value 0, then you start to go to value 1 with speed $q\to0$ and I also but with speed $q\to1$. Do we both reach each other at 1 in $\infty$ while I always am at front of you? it's hard for me to understand this!

Comment: Please remember that you're taking a sum.  If you fix $q$ at some number in $(0,1)$ then you can write the sum as $1-q+q-q^2+q^2-q^3+q^3......$, which has a limit of one because $q^n \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$ for all $0<q<1$.  It does not matter that you subsequently take the limit of $q$.  But if you first take the limit of $q\to 1$ you get that every term in the sum equals zero.  Another way of seeing what's going on is to write the sum as $\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^k - \sum_{k=1}^\infty q^k=1$.

Comment: I just have trouble to accept that $\lim_{q\to0}q^\infty = \lim_{q\to1}q^\infty = 0$!